# Как построить полоски вокруг кнопки

Tags: html, css

Хотел спросить, как построить вот такие вот элементы? 
Я знаю, что с помощью псевдо-элементов, но не знаю как жто сделать, помогите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="button-load-more">
    <button class="title" ng-click="loadMore(event)">load more comments</button>
</div>
```

вот мой CSS

```
.button-load-more
    display: flex
    -webkit-justify-content: center 
     justify-content: center  
    padding-top: 50px 
    padding-bottom: 60px
    button
      font-family: $book
      min-width: 220px  
      font-size: 17px
      opacity: 0.5
      background-color: none
      border: 1px solid lightgrey
      padding: 5px
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
:root {
  --color: lightgray;
}

fieldset {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid none none none;
  border-color: var(--color);
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid var(--color);
  color: #aaa;
  font-family: serif;
  margin: .4em;
  padding: .4em .8em;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend align="center">
    <button class="title" ng-click="loadMore(event)">load more comments</button>
  </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: К чему идет :root? У меня кнопка вконце страницы, написано на sass

Comment: Только увеличивая padding в fieldset - я получаю эти линии. Увеличивая padding - я увеличиваю место внизу блока.

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич если вы пользуетесь sass для вас не должно быть проблемы переделать все под себя. я предпочитаю ванильный css. По второму вопросу - это "эмуляция" того, что вам нужно. Просто погуглите зачем fieldset.

Comment: спасибо, я уже разобрался! Все работает, а на счёт fieldset - нужно ещё разобраться

Answer (score 2):

вот решение на нативном css c псевдоэлементами

```css
.button-load-more {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

.button-load-more::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 47%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

button {
  min-width: 220px;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  color: lightgray;
}

button::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-load-more">
  <button class="title" ng-click="loadMore(event)">load more comments</button>
</div>
```