# Как сделать заголовок с линиями по краям с помощью CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="line text-center">
        <h3 class="in-box">фасадные системы</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Данные вопросы должны сопровождаться желательным результатом. Я не понимаю например чего вы хотите

Comment: есть картинка наверху

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/880651/308317

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Не за что - в следующий раз постарайтесь поискать ответ)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как построить полоски вокруг кнопки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/880634/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8)